# Tangent lines of two curves just touching each other.

Tags: tangent-line

If two curves just touch each other, then how many tangent lines can be drawn from the point where these curves touch.

Comment: What does a "tangent line" mean to you in this context?

Comment: Recall the meaning of a tangent, and then you will see the answer.